# Grails encoding problem with GSP

Tags: tomcat, grails, encoding, utf-8, gsp

I'm having trouble with groovy server pages (gsp) where utf-8 chars are not showing propertly, and instead displaying as "?". This occurs inside grails tags like "${}".

Example:

```
<p>Não</p>  --> output browser: Não - OK

<g:link title="Avaliação Relatório"....> output browser: Avaliaç?o Relat?rio

${value? "Sim" : "Não"}  output browser: N?o
```

The gsp already are in UTF-8. My grails version is 1.2 M3 and in localhost the chars are showing ok, but in server (tomcat) they are not.

Thinking that was version problem, I upgraded to 1.3.3 and the problem still happens, but now on localhost too.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a definitive solution for you, but I'm suspecting you should have a look [here](http://grails.org/doc/1.3.x/guide/single.html#3.1%20Basic%20Configuration). I had problems with Swedish characters not showing in ${}, but that was because I had set...

grails.views.default.codec = 'html'

...which didn't work in my Javascript. That config or...

grails.views.gsp.encoding

...might give you the clue you need. Hope you find it!